# Rewrite rule for friendly URLs to index.php is not working from htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

Trying to get SEO Friendly URLs to work for my website using the following htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^explore/(.*)$ index.php?page=explore&type=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

E.g. it should load `/index.php?page=test` for `/test/` and `/index.php?page=explore&type=1` for `/explore/1`.

However it's not working, does anyone know how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have `RewriteEngine On` missing
2. `RewriteCond` are only applicable to next immediate `RewriteRule`

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^explore/(.*)$ index.php?page=explore&type=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I would have said the `QSA` and `NC` flags should only be used if required. There does not appear to be anything in the question that suggests these would be needed. (This seems to be the result of an edit by "Community"?)